# Software icon (from Sublime Text) isn't displayed in launcher

Tags: unity, software-installation, bug-reporting, sublime-text

I can start the software and find it over the dash, but no icon is shown (a blank sheet in the dash and a question mark in launcher).
Sublime Text is sitting in `/opt/sublime_text/` . `sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop` looks as following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=3.0
Name=Sublime Text 3
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Text Editor

Exec=sublime
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/sublime_text/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=sublime -n
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

I got also a "?" on icons from applications unity wants me to install from firefox (like tumblr, gmail).

Answer (score 3):

For me it helped to simply change a line in `/.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop`

**Wrong**: `Icon=sublime_text.png`
**Correct**: `Icon=sublime-text.png`

i.e. replace *underscore* by *dash* in icon name.

Comment: In my case, I cahnged `sublime-text` to `sublime-text.png`

Answer (score 2):

Had exact problem, adding the correct path to executable or softline resolved the issue for me

**Exec=/usr/bin/sublime %F**

Don't forget to quit and restart sublime for this to get updated.

Comment: wanted to add this as a thanks to devav2's answer!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I feel would be wrong is the path.Add a proper path to Exec.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;
```

Hopefully this should resolve the issue.

Comment: But I created following symbolic link `sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime` as they wrote in http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/install.html